# Matplotlib: Coloring scatter plot by density relative to another data set

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and having some trouble with matplotlib. I currently have data that is contained in two numpy arrays, call them x and y, that I am plotting on a scatter plot with coordinates for each point (x, y) (i.e I have points x[0], y[0] and x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIg6N.png), y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIg6N.png) and so on on my plot). I have been using the following code segment to color the points in my scatter plot based on the spatial density of nearby points (found this on another stackoverflow post):

http://prntscr.com/abqowk

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x*3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

idx = z.argsort()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y,c=z,s=50,edgecolor='')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output]

I've been using it without being sure exactly how it works (namely the point density calculation - if someone could explain how exactly that works, would also be much appreciated).

However, now I'd like to color code by the ratio of the spatial density of points in x,y to that of the spatial density of points in another set of numpy arrays, call them x2, y2. That is, I would like to make a plot such that I can identify how the density of points in x,y compares to the points in x2,y2 on the same scatter plot. Could someone please explain how I could go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing based on that same earlier post, and I think I just figured it out! The trick is to use `matplotlib.colors.Normalize()` to define a scale and then weight it according to some data set (xnorm,ynorm):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

def kdeplot(x,y,xnorm,ynorm):
    xy = np.vstack([x,y])
    z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

    wt = 1.0*len(x)/(len(xnorm)*1.0)
    norm = mplc.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=8/wt)
    cmap = cm.gnuplot

    idx = z.argsort()
    x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

    args = (x,y)
    kwargs = {'c':z,'s':10,'edgecolor':'','cmap':cmap,'norm':norm}

    return args, kwargs

# (x1,y1) is some data set whose density map coloring you 
# want to scale to (xnorm,ynorm)
args,kwargs = kdeplot(x1,y1,xnorm,ynorm)
plt.scatter(*args,**kwargs)
```

I used trial and error to optimize my normalization for my particular data and choice of colormap. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfPKU.png) what my data looks like scaled to itself; [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlL3U.png) my data scaled to some comparison data (which is on the bottom of that image).

I'm not sure this method is entirely general, but it works in my case: I know that my data and the comparison data are in similar regions of parameter space, and they both have gaussian scatter, so I can use a naive linear scaling determined by the number of data points and it results in something that gives the right idea visually.